# How to fix 'tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist', 'code': 34}]' when uploading Twitter background via Tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

When uploading a background image to Twitter using Tweepy, I'm getting the following error:

> tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist', 'code': 34}]

I can upload a status with an image via update_with_media and update_status, just not update_profile_background_image.

I am creating an image that uses ImageDraw.Draw to place text on the image. The text is the time between now and the 2020 Election (Nov 3, 7:00AM). Everything is working as expected (image creation, optimization, etc...) except the push to Twitter

Here's the error and code:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/twitter_countdown_bot/main.py", line 42, in <module>
        authenticate.update_profile_background_image(header_image)
      File "/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/twitter_countdown_bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 708, in update_profile_background_image
        return bind_api(
      File "/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/twitter_countdown_bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 252, in _call
        return method.execute()
      File "/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/twitter_countdown_bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
        raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
    tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist', 'code': 34}]
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    authenticate = auth_twitter.authenticate()
    # Sets path to image to have the text drawn onto
    header_image = str(update_header_image.update_header())
    # Create header image and push to twitter
    authenticate.update_profile_background_image(header_image)
```

update_header_image.py
Define what base image is used to write the text on

```
def update_header():
    image_file = create_image.createtwitterheader(headerimage=Image.open('images/TwitterHeaderImage.png'))
    return image_file
```

create_image.py
This is where the image is created and the path/name of the optimized file is passed

```
    #  Create the header image for Twitter
def createtwitterheader(headerimage):
    # Assign header text
    headertext = "As of " + date_calc.nowdict()["day"] + ", \n" + date_calc.nowdict()["month"] + " " + \
                 date_calc.nowdict()["daydate"]
    # Snatch up the fonts
    font = ImageFont.truetype("fonts/fira-sans/FiraSans-Heavy.otf", 76)
    font2 = ImageFont.truetype("fonts/fira-sans/FiraSans-Heavy.otf", 15)
    font3 = ImageFont.truetype("fonts/fira-sans/FiraSans-Heavy.otf", 35)
    # Draw the text
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(headerimage)
    draw.text((115, 195), emonth, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
    draw.text((229, 195), eday, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
    draw.text((106, 270), "M O N T H", (0, 0, 0), font=font2)
    draw.text((245, 270), "D A Y S", (0, 0, 0), font=font2)
    draw.text((350, 205), headertext, (255, 255, 255), font=font3)
    # Set path/filename
    filename_l = 'images/generated_images/twitter-header-' + date_calc.nowdict()["second"] + ".png"
    filename_s = 'images/generated_images/twitter-header-' + date_calc.nowdict()["second"] + "_s.png"
    # Save the image
    headerimage.save(filename_l, 'PNG')
    # Send to TinyPNG for image optimization
    source = tinify.from_file(filename_l)
    source.to_file(filename_s)
    # Show and tell (removed when in production)
    headerimage.show()
    return filename_s
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the wrong function. Instead of update_header_image , I should have used update_profile_banner.